# Does Yii2 create a default MySQL database for users?

Tags: mysql, authentication, yii2-advanced-app

I am testing the backend of [Yii2 Advanced template](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation). I have an error trying to login in the backend login page. It tries to connect to a MySQL database where I think there are a table for logins.

Is Yii2 also creating a database?

Here are my steps:

I created a project:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced my-yii2-backend
```

I initialized it:

```
php ./init
```

Then I run the php server:

```
php yii serve --docroot="backend/web/"
```

It's executed in localhost:8080 and I can see:

[image: Yii2 Advanced backend login]

Answer (score 0):

It does not create a database.

Yii2 does not presume to know what kind of database you might want or need so it does not create a database for you. Assuming you want to use something ubiquitous like mysql you could just create a database like : `CREATE DATABASE <dbname> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`. After you create the database [set up the database connection](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-databases#configuring-db-connection) in the configuration.

Further Yii2 does not presume to tell you exactly how to set up your user module or authentication, but if you want to use the framework hooks you have to implement `yii\web\IdentityInterface`.

If you read the few short paragraphs [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#login()-detail) it is explained.

Here is a suggestion to get you going:

1. Create and configure the database as suggested above
2. Run [this migration](https://gist.github.com/dataskills/2f62b4a108c7d463d3ab72a5b7bcceac) (or use it to create your own)
3. Use [this example](https://gist.github.com/dataskills/b07000951f9f6f7b89208e4ffe1c21b8) User model that implements `yii\web\IdentityInterface` (or use it to create your own)

> Note: Check namespaces, they could be different if you're using the Advanced >Template.